# Shrink Transaction Log for none active server

Tags: sql-server

Currently I have few database no longer active (No new entry), however my company does not want to drop it as they want keep it for reference purpose.

But due to huge database size I have difficult time to backup and restore. (Company policy, time to time have to backup and restore to test the database is workable or not).

So I'm thinking, I want to shrink the transaction log to reduce the time needed for the process, is that advisable to do that? Emphasize, since no new entry.

FYI, the transaction file (ldf) is much bigger than actual database size (mdf).

No matter is advisable to do or not, or even have better way to do please let me know.

Comment: 1) there are tons of Q/As and articles about "log trancation" in www or even SO 2) data backup does not include log backup

Comment: The brute force method is to detach the database files, rename then LDF, reattach _just_ the MDF and it will create a small LDF. Test the DB and if it still works you can delete the big (now unused) LDF. Make sure you actually do have a backup first

Answer (score 0):

I use this script

```
DECLARE @DBName varchar(255)
DECLARE @LogName varchar(255)
DECLARE @DATABASES_Fetch int
DECLARE DATABASES_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    select distinct
        name, db_name(s_mf.database_id) dbName 
    from
        sys.master_files s_mf
    where
        s_mf.state = 0 and -- ONLINE
        has_dbaccess(db_name(s_mf.database_id)) = 1 -- Only look at databases to which we have access
    and db_name(s_mf.database_id) not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb','distribution')
    and db_name(s_mf.database_id) not like 'MSDB%'
    and db_name(s_mf.database_id) not like 'Report%'
    and type=1
    order by 
        db_name(s_mf.database_id)
OPEN DATABASES_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM DATABASES_CURSOR INTO @LogName, @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 exec ('USE [' + @DBName + '] ; DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + @LogName + ''' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)')
 FETCH NEXT FROM DATABASES_CURSOR INTO @LogName, @DBName
END
CLOSE DATABASES_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE DATABASES_CURSOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good idea.  The easiest way to do this is first change the Recovery Model to Simple like this:

[image]

Then you can use Tasks; Shrink; Files to reduce the transaction log space to zero.   There are many resources to show you how to shrink a file, but this article explains it nicely:

[How to shrink the transaction log](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/)

Shrinking a file is not normally recommended, but it advisable if you do not expect more transactions.  This will save you time when you backup and it will take up less disk space.